# pathlib Path - create path instance and mkdir in one line

Tags: python, path, pathlib

Pathlib Path - looks like I cannot 'create a path instance' and 'mkdir' in one one line? Am I doing something wrong or this is not possible?

This returns None for region_path. WHY?

```
script_path = Path(__file__).parent.resolve()
region_path = Path(script_path/"device_details"/"region").mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
```

This returns a valid path for region_path, but I'm bothered by the extra step/line.

```
script_path = Path(__file__).parent.resolve()
region_path = Path(script_path/"device_details"/"region")
region_path.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This returns None for region_path. WHY?

Because, [Path.mkdir()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.mkdir) doesn't return anything.

> this is not possible?

It is *possible*:

```py
from pathlib import Path

(region_path := (script_path := Path(__file__).parent.resolve()) / "device_details" / "region").mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
```

But it seems like an abuse of the walrus operator so I would stick to the way you are doing it. As the [Zen of Python](https://peps.python.org/pep-0020/) says:

> Simple is better than complex.

> Readability counts.